# Assign min value or max value based on a value change

Tags: sql, oracle

**HAVE**

```
ID  cd dt       ct_vl
1   A  20210101 0
1   B  20210201 0 
1   A  20210301 0
2   A  20210101 0
2   B  20210201 1
3   C  20210101 0
3   V  20210201 1
3   C  20210301 0
3   C  20210401 0
```

**WANT** (Get min date when ct_val within the ID group is 0 across that ID group OR get max date within the ID group where ct_val is not 0 (that is it may contain a 1) across that ID group). For instance, if the ct_val within an ID group is 1, pick the maximum dt where ct_val within that group is 1

```
ID  cd dt       ct_vl final_dt
1   A  20210101 0      20210101
1   B  20210201 0      20210101
1   A  20210301 0      20210101 
2   A  20210101 0      20210201
2   B  20210201 1      20210201
3   C  20210101 0      20210301
3   V  20210201 1      20210301 
3   C  20210301 1      20210301
3   C  20210401 0      20210301
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `MAX` condition aggragte window function with `FIRST_VALUE` window function to get your logic.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN ct_vl = 1 THEN dt END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID),FIRST_VALUE(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY dt)) final_dt
FROM T t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fc52/2/0)**:

```
| ID | CD |       DT | CT_VL | FINAL_DT |
|----|----|----------|-------|----------|
|  1 |  A | 20210101 |     0 | 20210101 |
|  1 |  B | 20210201 |     0 | 20210101 |
|  1 |  A | 20210301 |     0 | 20210101 |
|  2 |  A | 20210101 |     0 | 20210201 |
|  2 |  B | 20210201 |     1 | 20210201 |
|  3 |  C | 20210101 |     0 | 20210301 |
|  3 |  V | 20210201 |     1 | 20210301 |
|  3 |  C | 20210301 |     1 | 20210301 |
|  3 |  C | 20210401 |     0 | 20210301 |
```

Comment: What's wrong with `min`?

Comment: Your solution works. I ended up incorporating David's suggestion as well                     
     `SELECT t.*,
       coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN ct_vl = 1 THEN dt END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)
       ,min(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY ID)) final_dt
FROM T t;`